# Distances between rankings

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scikit-learn

I have two methods that rank a list of strings differently, and what we can consider to be the "right" ranking of the list (i.e. a gold standard).

In other words:

```
 ranked_list_of_strings_1 = method_1(list_of_strings)
 ranked_list_of_strings_2 = method_2(list_of_strings)    
 correctly_ranked_list_of_strings # Some permutation of list_of_strings
```

How can I determine which method is better considering that `method_1` and `method_2` are black boxes? Are there any methods to measure this available either in `SciPy` or `scikit-learn` or similar libraries?

In my specific case, I actually have a dataframe, and each method outputs a score. What matters is not the difference in score between the methods and the true scores, but that the methods get the **ranking** right (higher score means higher ranking for all columns).

```
      strings        scores_method_1   scores_method_2   true_scores
5714  aeSeOg                    0.54               0.1           0.8
5741  NQXACs                    0.15               0.3           0.4
5768  zsFZQi                    0.57               0.7           0.2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for Normalized Discounted Cumulative Gain ([NDGC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain)).  It's a metric commonly used in search engine rankings to test the quality of the result ranking.

The idea is that you test your ranking (in your case the two methods) against user feedback through clicks (in your cast the true rank).  NDGC will tell you the quality of your ranking relative to the truth.

Python has [RankEval](http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/pbml/100/art-avramidis.pdf) based module that implements this metric (and some others if you want to try them).  The [repo is here](https://github.com/lefterav/rankeval) and there is a nice [IPython NB with examples](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/waylonflinn/8338948)

Answer (score 2):

The scikit-learn library also seems to have a NDCG (and DCG) metric implemented now.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ndcg_score.html#sklearn.metrics.ndcg_score