# Evaluating results from search query in python: ranked list vs. one manually labeled correct document

Tags: python, metrics, information-retrieval, evaluation, precision-recall

Given the following predicted ranked-list of documents:

```
query1_predicted = [1381, 1637, 646, 1623, 774, 1764, 92, 12, 642, 463, 613, ...]
```

and this manually marked best choice:

```
query1_manual = 646
```

Is there any suitable metric from information retrieval already implemented in python to rank this result?

I do not think that [NDCG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819093/distances-between-rankings/23820021#23820021) works for me because I am missing the true and fully ranked list of documents. I assume recall, precision, F-score and MAP also won't work as long as I don't have a full list of manually ranked results per query indicating the relevance of a document.

By the way: The length of the predicted list equals total number of documents in my collection:

```
len(query1_predicted) = len(documents)
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea is to combine the precision and recall metrics.
For example if your query returns a list where the correct document is first you can say that your precision and recall is 100%. If it is on the second place you have again 100% precision but your recall falls to 50% and so on. 
I know this approach is not perfect but it gives a good insight of your results with well known metrics.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
If I am getting you right my recall falls by 1/2 each document further down the predicted list the manually chosen one is located. So, I might end up having a very low recall with precision at 100%. 
I am guessing that I then need a non-linear solution to combine both measures. Isn't F-score solving this issue then? Could you help me with some kind of formula with precision (P) and recall (R) to compute a score value?

Comment: The recal will fall to 1/3 if the correct document is the third one, to 1/4 for the fourth one and so on. You can try the f1 score which uses precision and recall. Also ROC and Precision-Recall curves give a good insight of the performance of your method.